# How do i take an integer that was inputed through a in.nextInt(); and in.nextDouble(); and multiply those two together?

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    //last name,first name
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" Enter the name (Last, First): ");
    String firstToken = in.next();
    String restOfSentence = in.nextLine();
    String sentence = firstToken + restOfSentence;

    //phone number
    System.out.print(" Enter the phone number (###) ###-####: ");
    String phoneNum = in.next();
    String restOfNum = in.nextLine();
    String sentence2 = phoneNum + restOfNum;

    //Name of book
    System.out.print(" Enter the title of the book: ");
    String bookName = in.next();
    String restOfName = in.nextLine();
    String sentence3 = bookName + restOfName;

    //Date checked out
    System.out.print(" Enter the date checked out (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    String bookDate = in.next();
    String restOfDate = in.nextLine();
    String sentence4 = bookDate + restOfDate;

    // Days late
    System.out.print("Days late: ");
    in.nextInt();


    // Daily Fine
    System.out.print("Daily fine: ");
    in.nextDouble();

    //daily fine calculation
    fine = 
}
```

I need to take the days overdue and multiply it by the daily fine to get the total price of the fine. I Do not need it to be shown on the screen I just need it to be calculated for later when I do need it on the screen

Comment: Assign the results of `nextInt` and `nextDouble` to something?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
// Days late
System.out.print("Days late: ");
int daysLate = in.nextInt();

// You will probably need to get rid of the new line character here
in.nextLine();  

// Daily Fine
System.out.print("Daily fine: ");
double dailyFine = in.nextDouble();

// And here..
in.nextLine(); 

//daily fine calculation
double fine = daysLate * dailyFine;
```

- Store them in variables, multiply them.
- Use [Scanner#nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to clear away the new line character after integer and double inputs